# generating NDC from object space coordinates

Tags: opengl

Can anyone explain me what what are steps to be performed in order to generate NDC from object space coordinates with below example.

```
    float vertices[] = {
 -2.0f, -12.0f,
 2.0f, -12.0f,
-2.0f, 12.0f, 
 2.0f, 12.0f
    };
```

here is my mvp matrix:

```
        float MVP[16] = {

         0.993,  0.054, -0.102, -0.102,
 0.007,  0.852,  0.524,  0.524,
-0.115,  0.521, -0.846, -0.846,
0.575, -2.604,  4.061,  4.260 };
```

By my calculation I get:

X,Y,Z,W:

```
0.824918 7.111959 1.110172 1.000000
-1.111003 5.714332 1.090060 1.000000
-0.123152 0.698949 0.981588 1.000000
0.256286 0.747339 0.980855 1.000000
```

But those are wrong. By wrong I mean, if I do:

```
         vec4 vert =  mvp * vec4(inPos.x,inPos.y,0,1);
        vert.xyzw/=vert.w;
        gl_Position = vert;
```

in VS, i get different o/p as that of:

```
         vec4 vert =  mvp * vec4(inPos.x,inPos.y,0,1);
        gl_Position = vert;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I can't exactly reproduce the numbers you got. Maybe you rounded the matrix elements in the question. The values I get are:

```
V0: [0.819627 7.09211 1.1091 1]
V1: [-1.10977 5.69893 1.08916 1]
V2: [-0.123419 0.698661 0.981492 1]
V3: [0.255704 0.7471 0.980762 1]
```

However, the issue is something else. When you look at the clip space coordinates of those points, you get this:

```
V0: [-1.495 -12.936 -2.023 -1.824]
V1: [2.477 -12.72 -2.431 -2.232]
V2: [-1.327 7.512 10.553 10.752]
V3: [2.645 7.728 10.145 10.344]
```

Note several things:
The viewing volume is restriced by the inequality -w <= x,y,z <= w in clip space. The coordinates of V0 and V1 do not satisfy that inequality. So these points lie *outside of the viewing frustum*. In general, the GL will clip primitives which partly lie inside and outside of the viewing volume.

The clipping in itself is not the issue here though. Note that the `w` component of V0 and V1 is actually *negative*. This means that those points lie *behind* the projection center (= virtual camera). By dividing them by `w`, you mirror these points back *in front of the camera*. NDC coordinates of points which are behind the camera are mirrored in `x`,`y` *and `z`*, and skipping the clipping step will result in completely wrong primitives in this situation.

The GL will never have this issue, because the clipping will be done in clip space, before the division is done. If you want meaningful NDC coordinates, you also have to implement your own clipping. However, this can hardly be done in the Vertex shader (unless all you are drawing are separate points). For line or triangle primtivies, you need the data of all vertices to calculate the intersection between the primitive edges and the clipping plane(s), and you might have to create new primitives on the fly.

This also means that there just are **no meaningful NDC coordinates at all for points which lie behind the projection center.** For example, consider a triangle where two vertices lie in front of the camera, well inside the view volume, and the third vertex lies behind the camera. Clipping will create a new point on each of the edges from the third point to the others (and will generate two triangles replacing the original one). Those two new points do have meaningful NDC coordinates, but the third original point never has - and there is no 1:1 mapping between that third input point and the newly created points, either.

Comment: the numbers you got are the same I am getting except some round-off errors. is there any way to know how clipping is done by the GPU/ can we get the NDC same as generated by GPU ?

Comment: The NDC for what vertex?

Comment: I understand GPU generates new vertices before clipping. so how do we get coordinates of new rectangle in NDC which is rendered by GPU?

Comment: "NDC coordinates of points which are behind the camera are mirrored in x,y and z, and skipping the clipping step will result in completely wrong primitives in this situation."  can you please elaborate this part of your answer? does this mean before clipping GPU will revert the signs of x,y,z if it is lying behind the camera ?

Comment: @debonair: The GPU will not touch the signs. It will use the complete vertices as they are, in clip space, and intersect the whole primitive with the near plane (which is the relevant plane for this scenario). The resulting new vertices will by definition lie in front of the camera. The GPU will never divide any coordinate by a negative w, because all those vertices were removed before the division is done.

Comment: if we want to perform this manually, how would you suggest to do that? finding NDC of square? is it possible?

Comment: @debonair: It is totally unclear what you are trying to _achieve_ here. _If_ you need a NDC value per vertex, you could use a geometry shader and manually perform the clipping. Then, for every vertex that is actually rendered, you get a meaningful NDC value. If you just need some NDC value _per fragment_ in the fragment shader, there are much better apporaches.

Comment: I am trying to get NDC per vertex. And I want to do clipping for another bounding volume and it's NDC are known to me. So I need NDC per vertex. Can you specify how to do that?

Comment: @debonair: If you want to do clipping, the correct way is to do it in _clip space_ (hence the name), before the division. If your clip volume is known in NDC, you can simply transform _that_into clip space, instead of the other way around.

Comment: as per my understanding clip space is different for each vertex right? if so, then it wont make sense to transform rectangle with NDC to clip space and then compare this with object's clip coordinates to check for overlap.

Comment: @debonair: the space isn't different. the vertices just lie at different points. The difference is that there is just an additional dimension. And a clip plane in NDC will be some volume in clip space - but the key point is that you can test and intersect against a specific `w`-slice. It is just so that that slice is different for each vertex you are checking against, and also for the intersection points - but these lie on affine combinations of the input vertices.

Comment: sorry i meant to say the clipping bounds for each vertex is different but all of them are in clip space. So I tried NDC to clip space and then comparing the values for overlapping but it did not work though i did not debug this in detail.

Comment: so as per your suggestion, in question we see that first two vertices are behind the camera and first 2 vertices are below i.e. they lie at the bottom. so i calculated the equation of a line and substituted value of y=-1 to get the x-coordinate but the x-coordinate which i got does not match with the one which is GPU rendering. so i am wondering how it generates new vertices.